# wordpress ajax returning zero instead of string message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

My ajax call is returning zero even though I wrote `die()` at the end of my PHP function.
I looked over the other questions here and did not figure it out, please take a look at my code

I make an ajax call using this function:

```
$('.aramex-pickup').click(function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var pickupDateDate = $('.pickup_date').val();
    var pickupDateHour = $('.pickup_date_hour').val();
    var pickupDateMinute = $('.pickup_date_minute').val();
    var pickupDate = pickupDateDate + ' ' + pickupDateHour + ':' + pickupDateMinute;

    var orderId = button.data('id');
    if (pickupDate) {
        //show loader img
        button.next('.ajax-loader').show();

        var data = {
            'action': 'aramex_pickup',
            'order_id': orderId,
            'pickup_date': encodeURIComponent(pickupDate)
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                if (msg === 'done') {
                    location.reload(true);
                } else {
                    var messages = $.parseJSON(msg);
                    var ul = $("<ul>");
                    $.each(messages, function(key, value) {
                        ul.append("<li>" + value  + "</li>");
                    });
                    $('.pickup_errors').html(ul);
                }
            }, complete: function() {
                //hide loader img
                $('.ajax-loader').hide();
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Add pickup date");
    }

    return false;
});
```

in the back-end I wrote this function just to test the ajax is working ok:

```
public function ajax_pickup_callback() {
    echo 'ajax done';
    die();
}
```

I registered the action by:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_aramex_pickup', array($this, 'ajax_pickup_callback'));
```

all of this returns 0 instead of "ajax done".

Any help please?

Comment: What about register your action simply by : `add_action( 'wp_ajax_aramex_pickup', 'ajax_pickup_callback' );` ?

Comment: I'm using a class, I have to use array($this, to register it

Comment: your ajax url is `$$blabla$$/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` ?

Comment: yes, the ajax url is correct

Comment: Try to add an action for nopriv.
`add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_aramex_pickup', array( $this, 'ajax_pickup_callback' ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_aramex_pickup', array( $this, 'ajax_pickup_callback' ) );`

Comment: same issue with nopriv

Answer (score -1):

Actually your hook is not get executed. You have to pass the action in the ajax request as you can see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)).

```
jQuery.post(
ajaxurl, 
{
    'action': 'add_foobar',
    'data':   'foobarid'
}, 
function(response){
    alert('The server responded: ' + response);
}
```

);

Comment: Can you please show me exactly where he has added the action?????? Think before you downgrade the answer. Please show me the action as the name of hook....... @Steeve Pitis

Comment: `var data = {
            'action': 'aramex_pickup',
            'order_id': orderId,
            'pickup_date': encodeURIComponent(pickupDate)
        };`